# Preventing an 'Open Redirect' exploit on C# Web Forms Application

Tags: c#, redirect, c#-4.0

The code looks like the following- this is the apparent offending code:

```
readonly Regex alphaNumericRegex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$");
private const string USERNAME = "bitzleon";
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Get("userid") == null)
    {
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
        NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        query["userid"] = USERNAME;
        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
        if (alphaNumericRegex.IsMatch(query["userid"]) && IsLocalUrl(uriBuilder.ToString()))
        {
            Response.Redirect(uriBuilder.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The line `Response.Redirect(uriBuilder.ToString());` is throwing the error in my Veracode scans- but I'm running two checks to ensure the redirect is valid and internal.

Firstly, the query needs to be alpha-numeric- the regex takes care of that- and secondly, the url to which we are redirecting to is local only. The method I am using the validate the url is as follows:

```
public bool IsLocalUrl(string url)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    {
        return false;
    }
    Uri absoluteUri;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out absoluteUri))
    {
        return String.Equals(Request.Url.Host, absoluteUri.Host,
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
    bool isLocal = !url.StartsWith("http:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    && !url.StartsWith("https:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    && Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Relative);
    return isLocal;
}
```

But Veracode still doesn't think these fixes are enough to ensure the HARDCODED redirect is validated sufficiently.

[image: This is the full message on veracode.]

[This is the page](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/601.html) they take me to when showing examples of how this attack works.

I'd like to assume that this is a false positive, but it is still affecting my score nevertheless.

Comment: What error you are seeing?

Comment: I added the veracode screenshot to the main post.

Comment: Perhaps convert the url into a relative URL (Request.Url.PathAndQuery) and use the built in IsUrlLocalToHost() - Its never going to analyse your code to the point at which it will say "ah but there is a valid check to force a local url" so perhaps using a framework method will satisfy it.

Comment: Veracode now has a Community where they answer questions like these: https://community.veracode.com/s/questions